# Is class template instantiated when passed by reference?

Tags: c++, templates, class-template

Consider the following example:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
  void foo () const {t->foo();}
  virtual void fooVirtual() {t->foo();} // MSVC: use of undefined type 'B'
  
protected:
  T* t;
};

class B; // only forward declared

const A<B>& get(); // will be defined in another translation unit
void foo(const A<B>& a); // will be defined in another translation unit

int main () 
{
  const A<B>& a = get();
  foo(a); // MSVC: class template instantiation 'A<B>' being compiled
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles in CLang and GCC, but generates the error messages as mentioned above by MSVC. Which compiler behaviour is C++ compliant?

Should a class template specialization (`A<B>`) be instantiated when passed by reference?

See example at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9v89MMrfn)

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174161/is-a-virtual-function-of-a-template-class-implicitly-instantiated). If I understand the accepted answer correctly, it is not specified by the standard

Comment: This is similar to https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#9, but in your case I don't think an instantiation is required in the first place even if naively following the overload resolution rules since there is no overload that depends on the definition of the class.

Comment: @joergbrech Whether the virtual member function is instantiated is unspecified if the class specialization itself is instantiated. But if the class specialization itself is not instantiated, then (I supposed) it should also be impossible for the member function to be instantiated. Whether or not the class specialization may be instantiated is I think what OP is asking about.

Comment: With g++ (with warnings enabled via `-Wall`, etc) I get a *warning* from the compiler but the code compiles, then doesn't link since `main()` calls a function `foo()` that is not defined.    In any event, the standard specifies that, when something not defined is referenced, that there will be some diagnostic produced during translation (where compiling or linking as performed by real toolchains both correspond to distinct phases of translation) - it doesn't specify what phases of translation should emit a diagnostic.

Comment: @Peter I edited my question to clarify that `foo()` and `get()` will be defined in another translation unit to keep the scope of this question narrow enough.

Comment: I created a [MSVC bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Undesired-class-template-instantiation-/10525553).

Answer (score 5):

[[temp.inst](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-2)] "...the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program."

I don't see it being the case here. Let's replace the specialization with an incomplete type:

```
class A;
void foo(const A& a);

const A& get();

int main () 
{
  const A& a = get();
  foo(a);
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles just fine ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9zWschvh7)), so no complete type is required at this point. Adding a pair of curly braces after `class A` changes nothing. So MSVC is probably wrong.